# Linux pass value between parent process and child process using two pipes in c?

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

I have trouble with passing value between parent and child process using two pipes.. the code below works but the result is not what i want. need help to fix it. I want the two processes works parallel (parent->child->parent->child), not(partent->child->child->child..)

the output should look like this:

initial value 0

Parent:

x value after operation:1

Child:

x value after operation:10

Parent:

x value after operation:11

Child:

x value after operation:110

Parent:

x value after operation:111

Child

x value after operation:1110

Parent:

x value after operation:1111

Child

x value after operation:11110

However, the code below shows the output:

initial value 0

Parent:

x value after operation:1

Child:

x value after operation:10

Child:

x value after operation:100

Child:

x value after operation:1000

Child:

x value after operation:10000

Child:

x value after operation:100000

Parent:

x value after operation:11

Parent:

x value after operation:12

Parent:

x value after operation:13

Parent:

x value after operation:14

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 25
#define READ  0
#define WRITE 1

int main(void)
{
  pid_t pid;
  //open two pipes, one for each direction
  int mypipefd[2];
  int mypipefd2[2];
  int result=0;
  int i;


  printf("initial value %d\n",result);

  /* create the pipe */
  if (pipe(mypipefd) == -1 || pipe(mypipefd2) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed");
    return 1;
  }

  /* now fork a child process */
  pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
    return 1;
  }
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  if (pid > 0) {  /* parent process */  

    result++;


    close(mypipefd[READ]);      //close read end, write and then close write end
    write(mypipefd[WRITE],&result,sizeof(result));    //write to pipe one
    printf("Parent:\n x value after operation: %d\n",result);
    close(mypipefd[WRITE]);         //close pipe one read

    close(mypipefd2[WRITE]);        //close pipe two write
    read(mypipefd2[READ],&result,sizeof(result)); //read from pipe 2
    close(mypipefd2[READ]);  //close pipe two


    wait(0);
  }
  else { /* child process */


    close(mypipefd[WRITE]);   //close write end, read, and then close read end
    read(mypipefd[READ],&result,sizeof(result));  //read from pipe one
    close(mypipefd[READ]);        //close pipe one read  
    result*=10;                                                        
    printf("child:\n x value after operation: %d\n", result);


    close(mypipefd2[READ]);       //close read end, write and then close write end
    write(mypipefd2[WRITE],&result,sizeof(result));
    close(mypipefd2[WRITE]);
  }
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're closing paths while in the first iteration of the loop, and then you will execute the loop again... this time receiving errors on your I/O operations and having no change from attempting to read in the other end's `result`. Two changes for you to make:

First, add proper error checking on your I/O calls so that you can be aware of such problems. In general, if the functions have an error, -1 is returned (but look at their documentation to be sure).

Then... stop closing pipes that you still intend to use! Close them after the loop.

Comment: thanks for your comment. so do i need to close both pipe(read/write) after the loop?

Comment: It's fair to close the pipes you're never going to need before the loop and the pipes you're finished with after the loop. This will make the code a little uglier than it is now though, and there's nothing wrong with simply closing all of them after the loop. (As you're exiting, you could even let them be closed by the operating system for you, but that's not a good pattern to get in the habit of.)

Comment: i tried to put all the closing statement after the loop but it didn't work.